# How can I make the object recognize the color he is on top? In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

I'm working on a game in Unity that have a lot of mazes. I was doing it by adding 1 object per wall, but it's so much work anda I'm thinking on some new ways to do it, that make it easier to "build" the mazes.

What I tought was doing one image all white with the places where the wall should be being black. And then making my Player object recognize the black color as a collider or something like that.

Anyone know how to do it? Any other ideas are accepted to. Thanks guys.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, I don't fully understand what's being asked. Do you mean you want a 2D Image where white pixels represent empty spaces and black pixels represent walls and you want Unity3D to read that image and place the GameObjects for you?

Comment: No. Srry for being unclear. I want a image where white pixels would be the way that the player can walk and black pixels be the walls where Unity would add colliders so the player object cant walk through then. So i dont need to place collider by collider over each wall.

Comment: Does it matter to you if the game is 2D or 3D?

Comment: You could also look at it the other way and instantiate a 1x1 wall prefab wherever there is a white pixel.

Comment: Game Generator, actually the game is 2D, with the camera looking up from the maze, like old Pokemon games GTA 1. So I want the game 2D.

Comment: Leo Bartkus. Yeah, I want sometinhg like this, but i dont know how to make a script recognize where is black anda where is white.